# Accessing a list item's view and data at the same time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-viewholder

I am working on a messaging application and would like to set the chat bubble as coming from the left or the right depending on who the owner of the message is.

```
public class Message {
    public String messageText;
    public boolean mine;

    // ...Constructor
}
```

Inside `MessageAdapter` I have:

```
@Override
public MessageHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(this.itemResource, parent, false);
    return new MessageHolder(this.context, view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MessageHolder holder, int position) {

    Message message = this.messages.get(position);
    holder.bindMessage(message);
}
```

I have been following tutorials to migrate from ListView to RecyclerView and am now unclear as to how to access both an item's data and its view at the same time without getting `NullPointerException`. The code I want to use looks like this:

```
Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(message.mine ? R.drawable.bubble_right : R.drawable.bubble_left);
background.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

view.findViewById(R.id.message_text).setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

However, if I put it in `onCreateViewHolder` I can't figure out how to access the individual message to check ownership. If I put it in `onBindViewHolder` I have `message` but can't get its view. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are moving from ListView to RecyclerView, then it's very easy to understand.

```
getView() (of ListView) == onCreateViewHolder() + onBindViewHolder();
```

If you remember we need to check view given by getView is null or not, and if it's null then we need to take care of instancing otherwise set the data to corresponding views.
`RecyclerView` are making our life easy, the `onCreateView` creates new instance of the view of each row(minimum required) and `onBindViewHolder` takes care of binding data to each view element.

I think now you are clear why and how to handle these two methods of `RecyclerView`.
As per your code, the line `view.findViewById(R.id.message_text)` should be moved to your ViewHolder class.
And the following lines will go in onBindViewHolder

```
Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(message.mine ? R.drawable.bubble_right : R.drawable.bubble_left);
background.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
holder.your_view.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Let me know if you want to know further clarifications.

Comment: I understand that `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` together make up `getView`. However, I am unclear how to apply this knowledge in my specific situation.

As you can see in my question, I would like to set the background of a `TextView` to either `bubble_left` or `bubble_right` depending on whether `message.mine` evaluates true or not. I don't know how to acess both `message` and its view (to set the background) at the same time.

Comment: Updated my answer.